# Displaying website om APP

Tags: php, android, html, android-studio

I have my website wedeb.tk.
I wanted that I could also run that site on my phone using an app. But I dont know how to make an app such that the project is made

Kindly suggest some way

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast way, you can create a browser then open your page via browser. It's called Webview.

more :
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

you can use apkcreator in android to make this app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apkcreator.fwdfree&hl=in

Comment: Thanks for the help